# Private set of List in static class not working

Tags: c#, properties

I have a static class called `Bodies.cs`. The class has a List of Body, named `bodylist`.

I am trying to make it readonly from other classes, so that the other classes need to call some specified methods in Bodies.cs to change the contents of bodylist. However, they should be able to read its values freely.

I have searched extensively on Stackoverflow, but the examples given don't seem to help: either I get error messages, or null exceptions, or it's still possibe to do `Bodies.bodylist.Add(mybody)` from outside.

Here's my code in `Bodies.cs`:

```
    static private List<Body> bodylist;

    static public IReadOnlyList<Body> Bodylist
    {
        get { return bodylist; }
    }
```

With these settings, `bodylist` never gets updated (it's always null and the application crashes when I try to add a body to the list). I get the warning message saying:

> "Field 'Bodies.bodylist' is never assigned to, and will always have
>   its default value null"

.

Thanks for any help on how I should solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static bodylist will be initialized to null. You have to create an instance before accessing it. Change your code to

```
static private List<Body> bodylist = new List<Body>();

static public IReadOnlyList<Body> Bodylist
{
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Body>(bodylist); }
}
```

By returning the `ReadOnlyCollection` the client will raise an exception while trying to add or delete items.
Otherwise the Client could do something like this:

```
((List)YourClass.Bodylist).Add(element);
```

Comment: Great reply (as is the first one). For other users: note that the type is needed as well:          static private List<Body> bodylist = new List<Body>();

        static public IReadOnlyList<Body> Bodylist
        {
            get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Body>(bodylist); }
        }

Answer (score 1):

`bodylist` is private. It means you can modify it inside the container class.

Just initialize it :

```
  static private List<Body> bodylist = new List<Body>();
```

Or inside your static class constructor :

```
static Bodies()
{
    bodylist = new List<Body>();
}
```

Also you may want to make some modifier methods such add or remove to manipulate it.

I hope to be helpful for you :)